# Calculate the height for a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scrollview

In my project I have a simple `UIView` with a `UIScrollView` subview. I am trying to calculate the height based on the content within the `UIScrollView` with the following code:

[image]

file.h

```
@interface ScrollViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UILabel* topLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel* bottomLabel;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView * scroller;   
} 

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
```

file.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView* view in scroller.subviews)
    {
       scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
    }
    // print value 88.000000
    NSLog(@"%f", scrollViewHeight);
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewHeight)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I don't know why the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a couple things.  First, set a breakpoint at the beginning of that method and walk through your code one line at a time to see what it's doing.

Second, Depending on how your views are laid out, especially if you have views next to each other, that code might not work.  It'll also not work if there is vertical margin/space in between the subviews.  Instead, you might try this code when looping through the subviews:

```
for (UIView *view in scroller.subviews){
    if (scrollViewHeight < view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height) scrollViewHeight = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height;
}
```

This should get you the correct height.

Comment: What difference would horizontal space make?

Comment: Sorry, that probably wasn't clear.  I mean the height of the space in between two fields oriented vertically that aren't right on top of each other...the vertical margin between two fields.  I should have said vertical space, I'll update the answer.

Comment: How is it not working, what value are you getting?  The code checks each view's position + height to see if it is greater than the last greatest position + height.  The scroll view contentSize height should be the origin.y + height of the subview furthest down in the view space.

Comment: the return value is 655.000000 (is correct) but not work vertical height, the scrollview is fixed

Comment: If the scroll view is fixed, then double check the height of the scroll view's frame.  What value is returned if you add to the end of that method:  NSLog(@"%f", scroller.frame.size.height);

Comment: view.frame.size.height = 88.000000

Comment: You said: view.frame.size.height....I'm looking for scroller.frame.size.height.  Maybe that's what you meant, but I want to make sure.

Comment: sorry scroller.frame.size.height) 655.000000, but i don't know why not work the vertical scroller.

Comment: There's your answer. If scroller.frame.size.height <= scroller.contentSize.heigh, the scroller won't scroll.  The contentSize must be larger than the frame for it to scroll.  Make the scroller frame smaller, and you'll see some scrolling action.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6736/discussion-between-maurizio-and-aaron-hayman)

Comment: now work, thank you very much. The problem was scroller.frame.size.height. Thk Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

What is not working the setting of the height or the log statement?

That is not how you print a float, the `%@` is the format specifier for printing objects. Check out [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

What you need it

```
NSLog(@"%f", scrollViewHeight);
```

Comment: Thank , now print this value: 88.000000